# Injeção de dependencia com Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

Estou usando Ninject no ASP.Net MVC e tentando implementar, mas estou pegando um erro:

> Error activating ISessionFactory
>
> No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>
> Activation path:
>
> 3) Injection of dependency ISessionFactory into parameter session of constructor of type PersonRepository
>
> 2) Injection of dependency IPersonRepository into parameter personsRepository of constructor of type HomeController 1) Request for HomeController

Estou utilizando ISessionFactory no meu repositório, eu preciso dar bind nele?

Estou usando Fluent NHibernate.

Meu repositório:

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private ISession openSession;
    private ISessionFactory session;

    public PersonRepository(ISessionFactory session)
    {
        this.openSession = session.OpenSession();
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void CreatePerson(Person person)
    {
        openSession = NhibernateUtilities.OpenIfClosed(session, openSession);
        openSession.SaveOrUpdate(person);
    }
}
```

Meu controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository personsRepository;


    public HomeController(IPersonRepository personsRepository)
    {
        this.personsRepository = personsRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Person test = new Person()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "teste",
            Surname = "teste",
            Nickname = "teste",
            Age = 25,
            Division = "teste",
            Email = "teste",
            Lane = "teste"
        };

        personsRepository.CreatePerson(test);

        return View();
    }
```

Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        kernel.Bind<IPersonRepository>().To<PersonRepository>();
        return kernel;
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo,

A princípio é preciso que você faça o bind do seu ISessionFactory.

Segue um tópico do stackoverflow em inglês onde contém o bind.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694917/how-do-i-setup-my-repository-with-fluent-nhibernate